# BigQuery can't find job when using pagination

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I've been using this AppScript function that I took from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery) with slight modifications and it seemed to work fine, it just takes in a query and returns a 2D array. However, if the query is big and comes back with more `totalRows` than `rows` and therefore requires pagination, the job doesn't seem to be persistent and therefore I get the following error after the `while (queryResults.pageToken)`:

```
API call to bigquery.jobs.getQueryResults failed with error: Not found: Job cellular-nuance-292711:job_-i4Dk9W7JVKF2-W_5
```

The job never seems to show up in the job history or using the bq command line tool. Essentially, it's returning data on the first call but it's impossible to query that same job more than once as it just disappears.

Here's my function:

```
function runQuery(query) {
  var request = {
    query: query,
    useLegacySql: false
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, bigQuerySettings.projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;
  var projectId = bigQuerySettings.projectId; // This is just a mock declaration, it's actually declared elsewhere in the actual code

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }

  // Get all the rows of results.
  var rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }
}
```

I've been adding tons of logs and can confirm that the job is definitely coming back correctly after the first attempt, and that there's even data in the rows - the issue is simply when there's a pagination token because `totalRows` is bigger than `rows`.

Comment: `projectId` doesn't seem to be defined. I'm guessing that it is somewhere else but you should add a mock declaration in your question. Also, could you remove all the code after the while block? It doesn't add information to the question ;)

Comment: Made those changes! Any chance you h ave an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: I won't be able to help much as I've never used BigQuery. I'd try seeing if `https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/jobs/<project-id>` has the result and how big it is. I'd also double check that I'm using the advanced service of the version 2.

Comment: That's the weird thing - the job never shows up in the console or in the command line, whether it worked or not! And definitely using the latest version :/

Comment: The only reason I can think because the job is not showing up in the console or the logs is that the projectId configured for the job is different of the projectId used to look at the logs or in the console. Can you double check that?

Comment: All using the same project - easy to check because I'm doing this in a client's account and they only have one project anyway (but I did double check what project the script is associated with, what project is being passed to the function, and the project I'm looking for the logs in, and they're all the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to add location to the last part:

```
while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken,
      location: bigQuerySettings.location
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass location option to getQueryResults method.

```
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken,
      location: 'YourBigQueryLocation'
    });
```

It worked for me.